# c# code in control attribute in aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'd like to change the text attribute of a button according to the session landuage. So I write:

```
<asp:Button id="btOptIn" runat="server" 
    Text="<% = UI.Instance.TxtSubmit %>"
    onclick="btOptIn_Click" />
```

This does not work. I tried several other versions (like `Text='<%# Eval(UI.Instance.TxtSubmit) %>'`) but could not succeed.

The same code (`<% = UI.Instance.TxtSubmit %>`) works outside the quotes of the attribute. What is the syntax to make it work within an attribute of a control?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

```
<asp:textbox id="tbName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("test") %>' />
```

<%= %> is a shortened response.Write() and is never valid as an attribute, for any server tag.

<%# %> can be used, only if the conatainer is databound (the page in your case).

<%$ > can be used to access data in resources files.

In the Page_Load of you will have to make a call to Page.DataBind() for this to work.

Comment: Thank you Madhur, but I was not able to use "<%$ >" format. Can you give an example for that one?